# Ошибка при компиляции LaTex

Tags: latex

При компиляции файла pdf скомпилировался, но открытие не дает никакого результата : "Не удается открыть этот файл. Проблемы с форматом файла"
Программа Miktex, компиляция pdfLaTex, pdf-просмотрщик - Foxit Reader и Reader.

Содержание log привожу ниже

```html
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MiKTeX 2.9.6700) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2018.5.22)  22 MAY 2018 22:42
entering extended mode
**./_DIPLOMA.tex
(_DIPLOMA.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 4
Babel <3.20> and hyphenation patterns for 76 language(s) loaded.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\extsizes\extarticle.cls"
Document Class: extarticle 1996/10/08 v1.0 Non Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\extsizes\size14.clo"
File: size14.clo 1999/11/11 v1.4a NON-Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\exscale.sty"
Package: exscale 2014/09/29 v2.1h Standard LaTeX package exscale
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `largesymbols' on input line 57.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 57.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 57.
\big@size=\dimen102
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen103
)
(Styles/style.sty ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\cmap\cmap.sty"
Package: cmap 2008/03/06 v1.0h CMap support: searchable PDF
) ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\inputenc.sty"
Package: inputenc 2018/04/06 v1.3b Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks14
\inpenc@posthook=\toks15
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fontenc.sty"
Package: fontenc 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX package

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\cyrillic\t2aenc.def"
File: t2aenc.def 2005/09/27 v1.0i Cyrillic encoding definition file
Now handling font encoding T2A ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding T2A

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\t2aenc.dfu"
File: t2aenc.dfu 2018/04/05 v1.2c UTF-8 support for inputenc
   defining Unicode char U+00A4 (decimal 164)
   defining Unicode char U+00A7 (decimal 167)
   defining Unicode char U+00AB (decimal 171)
   defining Unicode char U+00BB (decimal 187)
   defining Unicode char U+0131 (decimal 305)
   defining Unicode char U+0400 (decimal 1024)
   defining Unicode char U+0401 (decimal 1025)
   defining Unicode char U+0402 (decimal 1026)
   defining Unicode char U+0403 (decimal 1027)
   defining Unicode char U+0404 (decimal 1028)
   defining Unicode char U+0405 (decimal 1029)
   defining Unicode char U+0406 (decimal 1030)
   defining Unicode char U+0407 (decimal 1031)
   defining Unicode char U+0408 (decimal 1032)
   defining Unicode char U+0409 (decimal 1033)
   defining Unicode char U+040A (decimal 1034)
   defining Unicode char U+040B (decimal 1035)
   defining Unicode char U+040C (decimal 1036)
   defining Unicode char U+040D (decimal 1037)
   defining Unicode char U+040E (decimal 1038)
   defining Unicode char U+040F (decimal 1039)
   defining Unicode char U+0410 (decimal 1040)
   defining Unicode char U+0411 (decimal 1041)
   defining Unicode char U+0412 (decimal 1042)
   defining Unicode char U+0413 (decimal 1043)
   defining Unicode char U+0414 (decimal 1044)
   defining Unicode char U+0415 (decimal 1045)
   defining Unicode char U+0416 (decimal 1046)
   defining Unicode char U+0417 (decimal 1047)
   defining Unicode char U+0418 (decimal 1048)
   defining Unicode char U+0419 (decimal 1049)
   defining Unicode char U+041A (decimal 1050)
   defining Unicode char U+041B (decimal 1051)
   defining Unicode char U+041C (decimal 1052)
   defining Unicode char U+041D (decimal 1053)
   defining Unicode char U+041E (decimal 1054)
   defining Unicode char U+041F (decimal 1055)
   defining Unicode char U+0420 (decimal 1056)
   defining Unicode char U+0421 (decimal 1057)
   defining Unicode char U+0422 (decimal 1058)
   defining Unicode char U+0423 (decimal 1059)
   defining Unicode char U+0424 (decimal 1060)
   defining Unicode char U+0425 (decimal 1061)
   defining Unicode char U+0426 (decimal 1062)
   defining Unicode char U+0427 (decimal 1063)
   defining Unicode char U+0428 (decimal 1064)
   defining Unicode char U+0429 (decimal 1065)
   defining Unicode char U+042A (decimal 1066)
   defining Unicode char U+042B (decimal 1067)
   defining Unicode char U+042C (decimal 1068)
   defining Unicode char U+042D (decimal 1069)
   defining Unicode char U+042E (decimal 1070)
   defining Unicode char U+042F (decimal 1071)
   defining Unicode char U+0430 (decimal 1072)
   defining Unicode char U+0431 (decimal 1073)
   defining Unicode char U+0432 (decimal 1074)
   defining Unicode char U+0433 (decimal 1075)
   defining Unicode char U+0434 (decimal 1076)
   defining Unicode char U+0435 (decimal 1077)
   defining Unicode char U+0436 (decimal 1078)
   defining Unicode char U+0437 (decimal 1079)
   defining Unicode char U+0438 (decimal 1080)
   defining Unicode char U+0439 (decimal 1081)
   defining Unicode char U+043A (decimal 1082)
   defining Unicode char U+043B (decimal 1083)
   defining Unicode char U+043C (decimal 1084)
   defining Unicode char U+043D (decimal 1085)
   defining Unicode char U+043E (decimal 1086)
   defining Unicode char U+043F (decimal 1087)
   defining Unicode char U+0440 (decimal 1088)
   defining Unicode char U+0441 (decimal 1089)
   defining Unicode char U+0442 (decimal 1090)
   defining Unicode char U+0443 (decimal 1091)
   defining Unicode char U+0444 (decimal 1092)
   defining Unicode char U+0445 (decimal 1093)
   defining Unicode char U+0446 (decimal 1094)
   defining Unicode char U+0447 (decimal 1095)
   defining Unicode char U+0448 (decimal 1096)
   defining Unicode char U+0449 (decimal 1097)
   defining Unicode char U+044A (decimal 1098)
   defining Unicode char U+044B (decimal 1099)
   defining Unicode char U+044C (decimal 1100)
   defining Unicode char U+044D (decimal 1101)
   defining Unicode char U+044E (decimal 1102)
   defining Unicode char U+044F (decimal 1103)
   defining Unicode char U+0450 (decimal 1104)
   defining Unicode char U+0451 (decimal 1105)
   defining Unicode char U+0452 (decimal 1106)
   defining Unicode char U+0453 (decimal 1107)
   defining Unicode char U+0454 (decimal 1108)
   defining Unicode char U+0455 (decimal 1109)
   defining Unicode char U+0456 (decimal 1110)
   defining Unicode char U+0457 (decimal 1111)
   defining Unicode char U+0458 (decimal 1112)
   defining Unicode char U+0459 (decimal 1113)
   defining Unicode char U+045A (decimal 1114)
   defining Unicode char U+045B (decimal 1115)
   defining Unicode char U+045C (decimal 1116)
   defining Unicode char U+045D (decimal 1117)
   defining Unicode char U+045E (decimal 1118)
   defining Unicode char U+045F (decimal 1119)
   defining Unicode char U+0490 (decimal 1168)
   defining Unicode char U+0491 (decimal 1169)
   defining Unicode char U+0492 (decimal 1170)
   defining Unicode char U+0493 (decimal 1171)
   defining Unicode char U+0496 (decimal 1174)
   defining Unicode char U+0497 (decimal 1175)
   defining Unicode char U+0498 (decimal 1176)
   defining Unicode char U+0499 (decimal 1177)
   defining Unicode char U+049A (decimal 1178)
   defining Unicode char U+049B (decimal 1179)
   defining Unicode char U+049C (decimal 1180)
   defining Unicode char U+049D (decimal 1181)
   defining Unicode char U+04A0 (decimal 1184)
   defining Unicode char U+04A1 (decimal 1185)
   defining Unicode char U+04A2 (decimal 1186)
   defining Unicode char U+04A3 (decimal 1187)
   defining Unicode char U+04A4 (decimal 1188)
   defining Unicode char U+04A5 (decimal 1189)
   defining Unicode char U+04AA (decimal 1194)
   defining Unicode char U+04AB (decimal 1195)
   defining Unicode char U+04AE (decimal 1198)
   defining Unicode char U+04AF (decimal 1199)
   defining Unicode char U+04B0 (decimal 1200)
   defining Unicode char U+04B1 (decimal 1201)
   defining Unicode char U+04B2 (decimal 1202)
   defining Unicode char U+04B3 (decimal 1203)
   defining Unicode char U+04B6 (decimal 1206)
   defining Unicode char U+04B7 (decimal 1207)
   defining Unicode char U+04B8 (decimal 1208)
   defining Unicode char U+04B9 (decimal 1209)
   defining Unicode char U+04BA (decimal 1210)
   defining Unicode char U+04BB (decimal 1211)
   defining Unicode char U+04C0 (decimal 1216)
   defining Unicode char U+04C1 (decimal 1217)
   defining Unicode char U+04C2 (decimal 1218)
   defining Unicode char U+04D0 (decimal 1232)
   defining Unicode char U+04D1 (decimal 1233)
   defining Unicode char U+04D2 (decimal 1234)
   defining Unicode char U+04D3 (decimal 1235)
   defining Unicode char U+04D4 (decimal 1236)
   defining Unicode char U+04D5 (decimal 1237)
   defining Unicode char U+04D6 (decimal 1238)
   defining Unicode char U+04D7 (decimal 1239)
   defining Unicode char U+04D8 (decimal 1240)
   defining Unicode char U+04D9 (decimal 1241)
   defining Unicode char U+04DA (decimal 1242)
   defining Unicode char U+04DB (decimal 1243)
   defining Unicode char U+04DC (decimal 1244)
   defining Unicode char U+04DD (decimal 1245)
   defining Unicode char U+04DE (decimal 1246)
   defining Unicode char U+04DF (decimal 1247)
   defining Unicode char U+04E2 (decimal 1250)
   defining Unicode char U+04E3 (decimal 1251)
   defining Unicode char U+04E4 (decimal 1252)
   defining Unicode char U+04E5 (decimal 1253)
   defining Unicode char U+04E6 (decimal 1254)
   defining Unicode char U+04E7 (decimal 1255)
   defining Unicode char U+04E8 (decimal 1256)
   defining Unicode char U+04E9 (decimal 1257)
   defining Unicode char U+04EC (decimal 1260)
   defining Unicode char U+04ED (decimal 1261)
   defining Unicode char U+04EE (decimal 1262)
   defining Unicode char U+04EF (decimal 1263)
   defining Unicode char U+04F0 (decimal 1264)
   defining Unicode char U+04F1 (decimal 1265)
   defining Unicode char U+04F2 (decimal 1266)
   defining Unicode char U+04F3 (decimal 1267)
   defining Unicode char U+04F4 (decimal 1268)
   defining Unicode char U+04F5 (decimal 1269)
   defining Unicode char U+04F8 (decimal 1272)
   defining Unicode char U+04F9 (decimal 1273)
   defining Unicode char U+200C (decimal 8204)
   defining Unicode char U+2013 (decimal 8211)
   defining Unicode char U+2014 (decimal 8212)
   defining Unicode char U+2018 (decimal 8216)
   defining Unicode char U+2019 (decimal 8217)
   defining Unicode char U+201C (decimal 8220)
   defining Unicode char U+201D (decimal 8221)
   defining Unicode char U+201E (decimal 8222)
   defining Unicode char U+2030 (decimal 8240)
   defining Unicode char U+2031 (decimal 8241)
   defining Unicode char U+2116 (decimal 8470)
   defining Unicode char U+2329 (decimal 9001)
   defining Unicode char U+232A (decimal 9002)
   defining Unicode char U+2423 (decimal 9251)
))
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T2A+cmr on input line 105.


("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\cyrillic\t2acmr.fd"
File: t2acmr.fd 2001/08/11 v1.0a Computer Modern Cyrillic font definitions
)<<t2a.cmap>>) ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\babel.sty"
Package: babel 2018/05/02 3.20 The Babel package

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\switch.def"
File: switch.def 2018/05/02 3.20 Babel switching mechanism
)
*************************************
* Local config file bblopts.cfg used
*
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\arabi\bblopts.cfg"
File: bblopts.cfg 2005/09/08 v0.1 add Arabic and Farsi to "declared" options of
 babel
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\babel-english\english.ldf"
Language: english 2017/06/06 v3.3r English support from the babel system

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\babel.def"
File: babel.def 2018/05/02 3.20 Babel common definitions
\babel@savecnt=\count88
\U@D=\dimen104

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\txtbabel.def")
\bbl@dirlevel=\count89
)
\l@canadian = a dialect from \language\l@american 
\l@australian = a dialect from \language\l@british 
\l@newzealand = a dialect from \language\l@british 
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\babel-russian\russianb.ldf"
Language: russian 2017/08/12 1.3j Russian support for the Babel system
Package b
```

Comment: log-файл поместился не весь. Ну, даже и не знаю - выкладывайте исходный текст, тогда. Лучше бы, чтобы это был минимальный пример, воспроизводящий проблему. Либо на какой-то файлообменник - файл целиком.

Comment: файл [log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1PG9XMmkFiBt6by4-8nCzbfq-CwMcPj3b) Он такой урезанный и есть. При второй компиляции выдалась ошибка 

style.sty  LaTeX Error: File `pscyr.sty' not found.

Comment: Странно, отсутствие  PSCyr не должно было вызывать ошибки компиляции (в старых версиях не вызывает). PSCyr - это дополнительный набор кириллических шрифтов. По начертанию некоторые из них похожи на стандартные мелкософтовые (times, arial). Его не могут включить в дистрибутив теха из-за лицензионных проблем (кажется) - кто-то считает, что начертания некоторых из шрифтов были "украдены".  Собственно, тех должен просто сообщить, что не нашел этих шрифтов и подставить вместо них свои  cmr. Скорее всего, ошибку вызывает что-то еще. Да, при желании, pscyr можно установить самому.

Comment: Да, `\usepackage{pscyr}` - можно закомментировать, если оно есть.

Comment: Закомментировала \usepackage{pscyr}. Ошибка ушла, появились 2 предупреждения 
hyperref.sty
Package hyperref Warning: Option `pagecolor' is not available anymore.

style.sty
Package biblatex-gost Warning: You set maxbibnames or maxcitenames different from their default value 3. Make sure that sorting works as expected.
 Файл pdf по-прежнему не открывается

Comment: Это просто предупреждения. Не думаю, что это так влияет на создание итогового документа. Попробуйте сделать для нас пример: в копии документа сохраните всю преамбулу, сохраните названия разделов, а содержимое разделов удалите. Если так документ будет создаваться нормально, то тогда можно найти раздел (по очереди оставляя в документе только один из разделов), который вызывает проблемы.

Comment: Как я понимаю, Вам дали пример оформления диплома, но его автор делал под Linux c использованием TeXLive. И возможно, при этом использовались какие-то внешние команды из Linux (тех это умеет) или еще что-то специфичное...

Comment: Итоговый документ состоит из нескольких документов, которые включены в него через \include{work} (например). Этот файл представляет собой как бы шаблон, который уже был скомпелирован автором шаблона. Я меняю в файле персональные данные и пытаюсь скомпелировать снова - не выходит. [Это мой файл](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jqWody__gXpunGTXOd4Llm5Zvw-l_XbU)  [Это шаблон](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ermh7kHis4ZMAO_BCzZrI2ajgWYNRQZV)

Comment: В общем, самая главная проблема - это Ваш редактор для latex. Не знаю, в чем Вы редактируете, но оно делает из UTF-8 (как в оригинале) файл с кодировкой UTF-8 with BOM (BOM - это такой маркер "юникодности" в начале файла). Так вот, миктех этот маркер не любит и поэтому все файлы, что Вы изменяете вызывают ошибки. В общем, либо насильно сохраняйте файлы в том редакторе без BOM, либо Вам надо сменить редактор. Например, на Akelpad или на специализированный TeXStudio.

Comment: Еще, у вас ошибка в команде \rd (Personal_data.sty) - Вы не можете там использовать знак подчеркивания. В латехе этот символ используется для нижнего индекса. Замените его, например, на линейки \rule.

Comment: И правда все мои файлы с кодировкой UTF-8.  С закомментированным `\usepackage{pscyr}` всё получилось. Спасибо